# Solution to the Rustlings from_into exercise

Tags: error-handling, rust

I've got a working solution to the Rustlings from_into exercise (i.e. the code compiles and all the tests pass). The task required that I implemented the `From` trait for `struct Person`. I've highlighted the relevant section inline with comments below.

```
// The From trait is used for value-to-value conversions.
// If From is implemented correctly for a type, the Into trait should work conversely.
// You can read more about it at https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.From.html
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Person {
    name: String,
    age: usize,
}

// We implement the Default trait to use it as a fallback
// when the provided string is not convertible into a Person object
impl Default for Person {
    fn default() -> Person {
        Person {
            name: String::from("John"),
            age: 30,
        }
    }
}

// THE BELOW IMPLEMENTATION IS WHAT I'D LIKE INPUT ON
//
// Steps:
// 1. If the length of the provided string is 0, then return the default of Person
// 2. Split the given string on the commas present in it
// 3. Extract the first element from the split operation and use it as the name
// 4. If the name is empty, then return the default of Person
// 5. Extract the other element from the split operation and parse it into a `usize` as the age
// If while parsing the age, something goes wrong, then return the default of Person
// Otherwise, then return an instantiated Person object with the results
impl From<&str> for Person {
    fn from(s: &str) -> Person {
        let s_as_vec = s.split(",").collect::<Vec<&str>>();
        let name = s_as_vec[0].to_string();

        if name.is_empty() {
            Person::default()
        } else if s_as_vec.len() > 1 {
            match s.splitn(2, ",").collect::<Vec<&str>>()[1].parse::<usize>() {
                Ok(age) => Person {name, age},
                Err(_) => Person::default()
            }
        } else {
            Person::default()
        }
    }
}

// END OF WHAT I'D LIKE INPUT ON

fn main() {
    // Use the `from` function
    let p1 = Person::from("Mark,20");
    // Since From is implemented for Person, we should be able to use Into
    let p2: Person = "Gerald,70".into();
    println!("{:?}", p1);
    println!("{:?}", p2);
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;
    #[test]
    fn test_default() {
        // Test that the default person is 30 year old John
        let dp = Person::default();
        assert_eq!(dp.name, "John");
        assert_eq!(dp.age, 30);
    }
    #[test]
    fn test_bad_convert() {
        // Test that John is returned when bad string is provided
        let p = Person::from("");
        assert_eq!(p.name, "John");
        assert_eq!(p.age, 30);
    }
    #[test]
    fn test_good_convert() {
        // Test that "Mark,20" works
        let p = Person::from("Mark,20");
        assert_eq!(p.name, "Mark");
        assert_eq!(p.age, 20);
    }
    #[test]
    fn test_bad_age() {
        // Test that "Mark.twenty" will return the default person due to an error in parsing age
        let p = Person::from("Mark,twenty");
        assert_eq!(p.name, "John");
        assert_eq!(p.age, 30);
    }

    #[test]
    fn test_missing_comma_and_age() {
        let p: Person = Person::from("Mark");
        assert_eq!(p.name, "John");
        assert_eq!(p.age, 30);
    }

    #[test]
    fn test_missing_age() {
        let p: Person = Person::from("Mark,");
        assert_eq!(p.name, "John");
        assert_eq!(p.age, 30);
    }

    #[test]
    fn test_missing_name() {
        let p: Person = Person::from(",1");
        assert_eq!(p.name, "John");
        assert_eq!(p.age, 30);
    }

    #[test]
    fn test_missing_name_and_age() {
        let p: Person = Person::from(",");
        assert_eq!(p.name, "John");
        assert_eq!(p.age, 30);
    }

    #[test]
    fn test_missing_name_and_invalid_age() {
        let p: Person = Person::from(",one");
        assert_eq!(p.name, "John");
        assert_eq!(p.age, 30);
    }
}
```

My primary question is: **how do I make this more idiomatic?** The pair of `split[n]()` calls seems wrong, but I'm not sure how to handle the various ways it would panic if I don't have explicit length checks.

Comment: The title should describe what the code is doing, so hpe my edit is OK.

Comment: You haven't said what the "from_into exercise" actually _is_.  Could you provide a short summary of what the code is required to _do_?  Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Congratulations on your Rustlings challenge. Your code seems fine and is easy to understand, however, as you said yourself, some parts of it don't seem idiomatic yet.

However, before I begin this review, I would like to mention that I consider myself a Rust beginner with a lot more experience in other languages. Keep that in mind while you read this review (and feel free to disagree and comment!).

## Use `clippy`

While [`clippy`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust-clippy) cannot work miracles, it can warn you about some lints. For example, the patterns in `split` are single character literals and thus should be written as `','`, not `","`.

## Reuse what you already have

The longest line in your code is the `match` on `parse`'s result:

```
// indentation removed for simplicity
match s.splitn(2, ",").collect::<Vec<&str>>()[1].parse::<usize>()
```

However, we already have `s.split(...)`'s result at hand. We don't need to split it a second time:

```
match s_as_vec[1].parse::<usize>()
```

If your concerned about the `n` in `splitn` then use `splitn` in your binding for `s_as_vec`. Note that the turbofish `::<usize>` isn't necessary, as `rustc` can infer its type by the use in `Person`.

## Use if-let when applicable

Back to the explicit length check. Instead of

```
if s_as_vec.len() > 1
```

we can use `get(1)` and check whether the element exist via `if let`:

```
if let Some(age) = s_as_vec.get(1) {
    match age.parse() {
        Ok(age) => Person { name.to_string(), age },
        Err(_)  => Person::default
    }
}
```

This also prevents us from accidentally changing one of the index locations, e.g.

```
if s_as_vec.len() > 2 {
    match s_as_vec[3].parse() { // whoops, wrong number here
 ...
```

## Defer possible heavy operations if possible

We don't need `name` to be a `String` unless we have a valid `age`. Therefore, we can have `let name = s_as_vec[0]` until we create the `Person`. This removes unnecessary allocations.

## All remarks above applied

If we apply all remarks above, we end up with the following variant.

```
impl From<&str> for Person {
    fn from(s: &str) -> Person {
        let s_as_vec = s.splitn(2, ',').collect::<Vec<&str>>();
        let name = s_as_vec[0];

        if name.is_empty() {
            Person::default()
        } else if let Some(age) = s_as_vec.get(1) {
            match age.parse() {
                Ok(age) => Person {name, age},
                Err(_) => Person::default()
            }
        } else {
            Person::default()
        }
    }
}
```

However, I personally would probably try to minimize the possible return paths and use a single `match` expression, but that's based on my Haskell experience:

```
impl From<&str> for Person {
    fn from(s: &str) -> Person {
        let parts = s.splitn(2, ',').collect::<Vec<&str>>();

        match &parts[..] {
            [name, age] if !name.is_empty() => age
                .parse()
                .map(|age| Person {
                    name: name.to_string(),
                    age,
                })
                .unwrap_or_default(),
            _ => Person::default(),
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's a great answer! I'm also much more experienced with other languages, but primarily C and Python, which both have a different mental model from Rust. Having the more functional insight from your Haskell experience is very useful

Comment: Is it possible that in the first code snippet of the section "All remarks above applied", there is a missing `.to_string()` for the `name` field in `Person { name, age }`? Other than that, very helpful explanation!

Comment: @hansmbakker Yeah, the `.to_string()` call was missing, thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with the details of that "challenge", but defaulting to a value when the from-conversion fails just seems wrong and not something I'd expect. I'd hence recommend implementing [`FromStr`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/trait.FromStr.html) instead and return an appropriate error in case the parsing fails.